Dual radiator fans
What happens if I install a secondary radiator fan facing front side of my  radiator on  GS310..my purpose is to make it even more cooler through a manual switch.
just a experimental what are your thoughts?

What are the specs of the fan you plan to install? Under what driving and environment conditions do you want to achieve better cooling?

i plan to install a fan from CBR250 which is smaller in dimension.since i don't have space to install parallel to stock fan am installing it on front side of radiator guard & activate it by myself via manual switch whenever i wish. i ride in hot environment conditions 40 degree & rainy conditions.the question is fixing the fan front side of radiator guard will it affect  or block the incoming air flow to radiator fins under normal conditions ? what are your thoughts kindly share this is an experimental stuff

If the fan's placement is not optimal, it could potentially interfere with the natural airflow around the radiator. Also ensure your bike's electrical system can handle the extra current draw.

Really not a subject expert, but I'd second @5n10m concern regarding potentially hindering natural airflow. From what I understand, combining fans in series does not increase the airflow. So you might end up with little to no extra cooling when running 2 fans instead of 1.
